# PHP Undefined Offset with fgetcsv

Tags: php, csv, undefined, offset, fgetcsv

Okay, I've spent several hours on this problem and I'm not sure what's going on. I think I just need a fresh perspective on this problem especially since I've been up for over 24 hours and the deadline for this is in five hours.

I am getting an Undefined offset notice for every single offset (0 to 907) when I try to use the data I pulled from a CSV. (It probably means I am not successfully pulling the data, but I am exhausted and would appreciate some help)

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
$lines = array();
$lines2 = "";

$one = array();
$two = array();
$three = array();
$four = array();
$five = array();
$six = array();

$header = "";

$footer = "";

$countLines = 0;

/*
* Open the file and store its data into an array
*/
$fp = fopen('db.csv','r') or die("can't open file");

while($lines = fgetcsv($fp)) {

        for ($k = 0, $m = count($lines) - 1; $k < $m; $k++) {

            $one[$k] = $lines[0];
            $two[$k] = $lines[1];
            $three[$k] = $lines[2];
            $four[$k] = $lines[3];
            $five[$k] = $lines[4];
            $six[$k] = $lines[5];
    }
    $countLines++;

}




fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");


/*
* Set up file header
*/
$header = "Header"
    ;


/*
* Set up file footer
*/
$footer = "Footer";

/*
* Prepare data for export
*/
for ($i = 0, $j = $countLines - 1; $i < $j; $i++) {


            $lines2 .= $one[$i] ." ". 
            $two[$i] ." ". 
            str_pad($three[$i], 3) ." ". 
            str_pad($four[$i], 30) ." ". 
            str_pad($five[$i], 30) ." ". 
            str_pad($six[$i], 30) ."\r\n";

}

/*
* Store data in file
*/
$fp = fopen('db2.csv', 'w') or die("can't open file");

fwrite($fp, $header);

fwrite($fp, $lines2);

fwrite($fp, $footer);

fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");
```

The CSV file is a standard comma-delimited file so I don't see any reason to post that data here.

Comment: Without a real error message, and pressing for an answer with something like ASAP ... you will probably be out of luck.

Comment: @Martin Hohenberg, I do not think he was being rude by writing ASAP. He was relaying the urgency of his situation.

Comment: It's all in the error message, it will give you the line of code. Use `var_dump` to inspect your variables if they contain what you expect.

Comment: See my answer - implement it and then get some rest. even for an hour or two. Coding whilst exhausted is counter productive and slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement

```
while($lines = fgetcsv($fp)) {
```

[fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) will return a single line in the form of an array containing the elements on the line;

Therefore the following is wrong and needs to be removed as you are iterating over a single line in the CSV

```
   for ($k = 0, $m = count($lines) - 1; $k < $m; $k++) {
```

So, after revision the reading loop should (I think) be like this:

```
$fp = fopen('db.csv','r') or die("can't open file");
$k=0;
while($lines = fgetcsv($fp)) {
            $one[$k] = $lines[0];
            $two[$k] = $lines[1];
            $three[$k] = $lines[2];
            $four[$k] = $lines[3];
            $five[$k] = $lines[4];
            $six[$k] = $lines[5];
    $k++;
    $countLines++;
}
```

After this use, e.g. print_r($one) for debug to view the arrays.

To output it I'm relying heavily on guesswork as to what you want to achieve, because you are outputting to db2.csv, but without commas (to seperate). however try something like the following

```
/*
 * Store data in file
 */
$fp = fopen('db2.csv', 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fp, $header);

/*
 * Data for export
 */
for ($i = 0, $j = $countLines - 1; $i < $j; $i++) {
    fprintf($fp, "%s %s %-3s %-30s %-30s %-30s\r\n", /* possibly add commas here? */
            $one[$i], $two[$i], $three[$i],$four[$i], $five[$i], $six[$i]);

}
```

Comment: You are amazing! Thanks so much, I can't believe how much time I spent on that and it was just a simple loop issue. That's what I get for copying code from another one of my projects and not looking at it closely enough.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same one and look for a solution as you ...
In fact it's really simple and diabolic :`fgetcsv()` add an array with one `NULL` value at the end of the reading. Therefore, `$lines[1]` will produce an error, because the last added array has only one value.

Just count the number of columns in $lines like this :

```
/*
* Open the file and store its data into an array
*/
$fp = fopen('db.csv','r') or die("can't open file");

while($lines = fgetcsv($fp)) {

    if ( count($lines) == 6 )
    {

        for ($k = 0, $m = count($lines) - 1; $k < $m; $k++) {

           $one[$k] = $lines[0];
           $two[$k] = $lines[1];
           $three[$k] = $lines[2];
           $four[$k] = $lines[3];
           $five[$k] = $lines[4];
           $six[$k] = $lines[5];
        }
    }
    $countLines++;

}
```